# How to change Yolov5 tflite model output to float32?

Tags: yolov5, tflite

Here You can see the StatefulPartitionedCall:3 gives the int32 but I need to have it all in float32, Is there any way to get 4 float32 tflite models from Yolov5?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use default quantization (Float32) of TFLIte converter to get float32 . You can also force output type to float32 using below command.

```
converter.inference_input_type = tf.float32
converter.inference_output_type = tf.float32
```

Attached relevant threads for reference.
Ref [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization)